# Ctrl+Space mapping broken in Vim after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vim

I recently upgraded to Trusty via reformatting my system partition and keeping my home partition intact. Everything has gone smoothly except my mapping of Ctrl-Space to Escape in Vim no longer works. The line in my vimrc is `inoremap <C-Space> <Esc>` and when I run '`:imap`' inside vim I see the mapping is there. But nothing happens when I try it.

I'm especially baffled because all other Control assisted combinations see to work perfectly fine and I never had any issue with mapping Space before the upgrade. Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly relevant: I upgraded from 13.10 32-bit to 14.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume it is the same issue as described in [lp bug#1278511](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1278511), in which case running `ibus-setup` and disabling `Control+Space` should do the trick.